# ASP textbox calls javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a search textbox in asp. And I want it to send request to the server each time the text is changed there. I have a javascript function which sends request but it is not being called each time when I type something in the text box. How can I call javascript function from ASP textbox?

That is my textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="search" name="Search" runat="server" onchange="javascript:text_changed();"></asp:TextBox>
```

That is my js function:

```
function text_changed() {
     searchedword = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_search").value;
     SendRequest();
}
```

Comment: Paste your code for `SendRequest` - How is this accessing the search term?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use onKeyPress event to call the function.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="search" name="Search" runat="server" onKeyPress="javascript:text_changed();"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: onKeyPress and onKeyUp - it seems the value is one behind what you typed in the key press but matches exactly in the key up.

Answer (score 3):

Shivam's answer is right. You can use KeyPress event to get users key strokes with that event.

But i want to inform you, you should not use ASP.NET control ids like that :

```
document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_search").value;
```

Because you'll get errors if you put your textbox somewhere else in html hierarchy, ASP.NET regenerates it's id.

Try that one, instead :

```
function text_changed(textObj) {
     searchedword = textObj.value;
     SendRequest();
}

<asp:TextBox ID="search" name="Search" runat="server" 
  onKeyPress="javascript:text_changed(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you asking can achieve by

Use onkeyup or onkeydown instead.

This will then run the function when you type or click on the textbox. You can also then detect the keycode of the event, and prevent the function if you dont want it to run for certain keys.

Use the below code

```
    $("#search").keydown(function(){
    text_changed();
  });
  $("#search").keyup(function(){
    text_changed();
  });
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/antoKing/gFkY2/)

Answer (score 0):

give it a try :)

```
$("#search").change(function(){
      //your ajax codes
});
```

Comment: The user didn't state that they were using jQuery, so this won't help him (unless he/she does).

Comment: how would i know that :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
function multy(val)
{
alert(val.value+"--"+val.id);
}
</script>
<input id="txtdemo" type="text" onchange="multy(this);"></br>
<input id="txtdemo" type="text" onchange="multy(this);">
</input>
```

[image: Click to see out put screen]

Thanks... :)

Comment: he is expecting to be done with asp.net textbox control, because he might have some events already written with the control