# asp.net textbox lostfocus javascript call, code looks good but not compiling

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, lost-focus

I don't understand what is wrong with my code.
It is very basic, but still there is an error.

In the header tag I have the following script, you can skip your attention to the last function, which is the one I need for this question:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function allowOnlyNumber(evt)
        {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode

            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46)
                return false;


          return true;
        }

        function checkboxalert() {
            var active = document.getElementById("chkActive").checked;
            var inactive = document.getElementById("chkInactive").checked;

            if ((!active) && (!inactive)) alert("Please ensure that either Active or Inactive is checked before limiting search, otherwise, Active records will be assumed...")
        }


        function lostfocusLowPrice() {
            if (getElementById("txtFindHighPrice").value = "" && getElementById("txtFindLowPrice").Value != "") getElementById("txtFindLowPrice").Value = getElementById("txtFindLowPrice").Value;
        }


    </script>
```

In the design of my web page, I have this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFindLowPrice" OnTextChanged="lostfocusLowPrice()" onkeypress="return allowOnlyNumber(event)" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="63px"></asp:TextBox>
```

I get a compilation error:

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'lostfocusLowPrice' and no extension method 'lostfocusLowPrice' accepting a first argument of type 'webform1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Spelling matches.  Code is very basic.  Can't imagine what it might be.  Other javascript functions work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Amamath has a good answer below, but is there a client side solution for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnTextChanged event is a server side event so here it is searching the lostfocusLowPrice method in .cs file and throwing the above error.
for learn more about OnTextChanged  event. Please refer below link.
https://meeraacademy.com/textbox-autopostback-and-textchanged-event-asp-net/

below one also:
[ASP textbox calls javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797445/asp-textbox-calls-javascript-function)

Comment: good answer.  so is there a client-side solution to do what I am trying to do?